# how to add android:layout_marginBottom rule in code?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

layout.xml code part:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+android:id/listWhatever"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/rlSomething" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="I need this to set in code dinamically!"/>
```

Java code part:

```
listWhatever = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listWhatever);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) listWhatever.getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.addRule(android:layout_marginBottom ... , how?);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
layoutParams.bottomMargin=0;//your bottom margin value
listWhatever.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

You can use `RelativeLayout./insert static constant/` with addRule

Comment: It should work. Maybe is it padding you are looking for?
listWhatever.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
(Can't see your comment anymore, but I won't delete this :) )

Comment: it will be accepted, since is working, needed a rebuild, but need to wait 5 min, because of SO stupid rules "You can accept an answer in 4 minutes"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 LayoutParams lp= (LayoutParams) list.getLayoutParams();
 lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
 list.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: that is not equivalent with android:layout_marginBottom, but be happy: +1